# Remote Registry error

Tags: wso2-esb

Have wso2 esb version 4.0.3 on windows 2008 R2.  runs fine when using embedded registry.  when configure fro remote registry (running mysql 5.5), I get the following error

java.sql.SQLException: Total number of available connections are less than the total number of committed connections

and the esb will not start.  Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

execute the following command in mysql to see max_connections:
"show variables".
And execute "Set global max_connections=500" to increase the max connections.

Comment: No luck. See the error log below. There are no users on the server yet. only 9 total connections